# How to use Linux host for NAT and port forwarding

Tags: linux, debian, routing, port-forwarding, nat

I have Debian 9 host, with 2 interfaces:

- eth0, connected to internet; has dynamic IP assigned by ISP
- eth1, connected to LAN switch; has static IP; has established warm friendly relations with dhcpd

I have goal to force this PC to work as typical home router does - to "share internet connection", to forward traffic. Above tweaks were not suffient for routing traffic. I have found some way to turn it on:

```
modprobe iptable_nat
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

When I typed it as `root` I achieved desired result. Besides i dont understand what is going on here, (e.g. "can i replace `MASQUERADE` with `POOL_PARTY`?" - a great example of not self-explaining command syntax!) the main problem that these strings looks like quite low level tuning (stubs to achieve desired behaviour temporarily?) as it does not survives reboot. After reboot:

- `lsmod | grep ip` shows me that module is loaded
- `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` prints `0`
- `sudo iptables -S` gives empty rules list

I mean how usually such task is done on a routing/firewall linux servers? Are there a way to configure it other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> these strings looks like quite low level tuning (stubs to achieve desired behaviour temporarily?) as it does not survives reboot. […]
>   how usually such task is done on a routing/firewall linux servers? Are there a way to configure it other way?

Higher level is to have a firewall software (e.g. `shorewall` or `ufw`) that will set packet filter rules at every boot according to its configuration.

If you know how to run any command at boot (`/etc/rc.local` is a most basic method, not necessarily the best), you can run your `iptables` commands this way. This is like a poor man's solution.

Additionally see `man 8 iptables-save` and `man 8 iptables-restore`.

A basic way to permanently change `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`. You may even have these lines in the file:

> ```
> # Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
> #net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
> ```

You may not need to edit the file though, if you use a firewall that is smart enough to change the setting on its own whenever you need it, when the firewall works. I cannot tell which firewalls do this (if any) but it's possible in general.

---

> a great example of not self-explaining command syntax

Why should it be self-explaining? We have `man` and other resources for this. `man 8 iptables` will point you to `man 8 iptables-extensions` which is quite huge. I dare you to invent a self-explaining syntax that is able to replace the manual. :)

---

> I have Debian 9 host, with 2 interfaces […] to work as typical home router does

My setup exactly. I'm fine with `shorewall`.